# How to keep open multiple tree list using single toggle button in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make my custom tree list using UL and LI with PLUS/MINUS button.
The structure would be like as follows.

```
1
 1.1
 1.2
2
 2.1
 2.2
 2.3
```

1 and 2 will keep the icon as PLUS and when we click on anyone one respective icon will convert into MINUS. I want to use a single toggle method here. It is because a tree has n number of data.

I am able to create this structure but not able to implement a single toggle button for all node for toggling.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index;-">
    <span (click)="toggle(i)" style="cursor:pointer; font-size: 13px;">
      <i class="pull-left float-xs-left" style="font-size:13px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:3px; cursor:pointer;" [ngClass]="{'fa icon-minus': selectedIndex==i, 'fa icon-plus': selectedIndex!=i}"></i>
            {{item.id}} &nbsp; {{item.name}}
    </span>          
  </li>
</ul>
```

and typescript component file will be like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log',
  templateUrl: './log.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log.component.css']
})
export class LogComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedIndex: number;
  public data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: '073801',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: '04-25' },
        { id: 3, name: '25' },
        { id: 4, name: '25' },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '05602',
      children: [
        { id: 6, name: '04-25' },
        { id: 7, name: '04-25' }
      ]
    }
  ];



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle(index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

}
```

Basically, I would like to keep open that node which is opened until you don't toggle this. We can open multiple nodes at the same time.

Please guide me on this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep an `isOpen` property with each element of your `data` array to track if the element is open/closed. Also show the child `ul` only if the parent `isOpen` is `true`.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index;">
        <span (click)="toggle(item)" style="cursor:pointer; font-size: 13px;">
            <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-minus': item.isOpen, 'fa-plus': !item.isOpen}"></i>
            {{item.id}} &nbsp; {{item.name}}
        </span>
        <ul *ngIf="item.isOpen">
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.children; let i2=index;">
                    {{child.id}} &nbsp; {{child.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then use the toggle function to toggle the value of isOpen

```
  toggle(item:any) {
    item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;    
  }
```

See the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgvsfv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that. I know it's a little dirty, but you'll get an idea. You can also insert a `selected` key inside your object and set it to `true` or `false`.

**.ts**

```
public selectedIndex: number[] = [];
public data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: '073801',
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: '04-25'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: '25'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: '25'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: '05602',
    children: [
      {
        id: 6,
        name: '04-25'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: '04-25'
      }
    ]
  }
];

toggle(index: number) {
  if (!this.isToggled(index)) {
    this.selectedIndex.push(index);
  } else {
    this.selectedIndex.splice(this.selectedIndex.indexOf(index), 1);
  }
}

isToggled(index: number): boolean {
  return this.selectedIndex.indexOf(index) !== -1;
}
```

**.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
    <span (click)="toggle(i)" style="cursor:pointer; font-size: 13px;"
      >
      <i
        class="pull-left float-xs-left"
        style="font-size:13px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:3px; cursor:pointer;"
        [ngClass]="{ 'fa icon-minus': selectedIndex == i, 'fa icon-plus': selectedIndex != i }"
      ></i>
      {{ item.id }} &nbsp; {{ item.name }}
      <ng-container *ngIf="isToggled(i)">
        <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
          <span style="font-size: 13px;"> {{ child.id }} &nbsp; {{ child.name }} </span>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of booleans, let's call it `states`, you store the state of the toggles there, and your `toggle(i)` method will just do a NOT operation on `states[i]` and inside your `*ngFor`, for the i'th element, you check the value of `states[i]` and based on that you make it toggled or not.
If it's not clear let me know.